# Use cURL in PowerBi

Tags: curl, powerbi

Is it possible to connect dataset via cURL to PowerBI ?

I have cURL generate by graphql but not sure i I can use it somehow in PB

```
curl 'https://api.com/graphql' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: https://api.com' -H 'access_token: <my Token>' --data-binary '{"query":"# Write your query or mutation here\n{\n  members{\n    data{\n      user{\n        name\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n"}' --compressed
```

So far I managed to create below m code but i doesnt work. Im newbie to M language, can someone support me with it?

```
let
    apiUrl = "https://apiname.com/graphql",
    options = 
        [Headers =[#"Content-Type"="application/json", #"Subscription-Key"="<my token>"],
        Content = Text.ToBinary({"query:{\n  members{\n    data{\n      user{\n        name\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n"})
    ],
    Content = options[Content]
in
    Content
```

Error message: We cannot converte List type to Text type